# Child input boxes close navigation dropdowns on click

Tags: jquery, events, drop-down-menu, navigation

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4PMwP/

I'm using the following script for my navigation bar:

```
(function($){

  var timeout    = 500;
  var closetimer = 0;
  var ddmenuitem = null;

  // From https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/modernizr.js
  var isTouch = ('ontouchstart' in window) ||
                window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch;

  // jsddm funcs from http://javascript-array.com/scripts/jquery_simple_drop_down_menu/
  function jsddm_open($this){
    jsddm_canceltimer();
    jsddm_close();
    ddmenuitem = $this.find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');
  }

  function jsddm_close() {
    if(ddmenuitem){
      ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
      ddmenuitem = null;
    }
  }

  function jsddm_timer() { 
    closetimer = window.setTimeout(jsddm_close, timeout);
  }

  function jsddm_canceltimer() { 
    if(closetimer)
    {  window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
       closetimer = null;
    }
  }

  function jsddm_toggle($this) {
    if (ddmenuitem && $this.has(ddmenuitem[0]).length){
      jsddm_close();
    }
    else {
      jsddm_open($this);
    }
  }

  $.fn.make_dropdown = function(options){

    return this.each(function(){

      if (options && options['timeout']){
        timeout = options['timeout'];
      }

      $(this).click(function(event){
        jsddm_toggle($(this));
        event.stopPropagation();
      });
      if (!isTouch){
        $(this).mouseover(function(){ jsddm_open($(this)) }).mouseout(jsddm_timer);
      }

    });
  }

  $(document).click(jsddm_close);

})(jQuery);
```

The dropdowns display when hovered or clicked, which works great for desktop and mobile browsers. The problem is that my dropdowns will include input boxes for search, login, etc. and clicking these should NOT close the dropdown. Since everything in the dropdown is a child of the li that's listening for clicks, is closes no matter what.

I need the dropdowns to remain visible when child elements are clicked, but still toggle when the main parent li is clicked.

Thanks

Comment: Did any of these answers help you?

Comment: Sure did. Without asking another question, any idea how I'd enable it to also not close the dropdown while the input box is active? So it doesn't disappear while users are typing, etc

Comment: Here you go the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pF8Rp/. I will have my answer updated too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menubar > li').make_dropdown();
    $('li  input').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GrHT/)

You can stop the click event from bubbling up the parent tree by disabling it using `event.stopPropagation` at the input level. This will prevent the other parent click handlers from being executed.

Plus i am not sure if this is apt in your case but:

Use `mouseenter/mouseleave`(`hover`) events as opposed to `mouseover/mouseout` events as the latter will get triggered even if you hover over a child inside the parent where the events are bound.

*from **[docs](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)***

> The mouseenter event differs from mouseover in the way it handles event bubbling. If mouseover were used in this example, then when the mouse pointer moved over the Inner element, the handler would be triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The mouseenter event, on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse enters the element it is bound to, not a descendant. So in this example, the handler is triggered when the mouse enters the Outer element, but not the Inner element.

#### Update

Based on your comment in the question: when input box is active no menus will come up, this will hide too on mouse out. Only on enter key press on the int box the menu will be hidden. Just based on my assumptions of

```
    // on Search Box click    
    $('li  .searchBox').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }).keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) // on enter key press close
        {
            $('.searchBox').closest('ul').css('visibility', 'hidden'); // SInce you are using visility for you menus. You can also try calling your method to hide, But this is a pointer
        }
    });
```

And on open close

```
function jsddm_open($this) {
        if ($('.searchBox').css('visibility') == 'hidden') { // Dont show any other menu when searchbox is active
            jsddm_canceltimer();
            jsddm_close();
            ddmenuitem = $this.find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
    }

    function jsddm_close() {
        if ($('.searchBox').css('visibility') == 'hidden') { // check if the input is visible if not then do this.

            if (ddmenuitem) {
                ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
                ddmenuitem = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U2LvK/)**

Answer (score 0):

Check this DEMO, http://jsfiddle.net/4PMwP/12/

Give an ID to your input and added in one line `$('#showInput').click(jsddm_open);` after your `$(document).click(jsddm_close);` script.

```
(function($){

  var timeout    = 500;
  var closetimer = 0;
  var ddmenuitem = null;

  // From https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/modernizr.js
  var isTouch = ('ontouchstart' in window) ||
                window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch;

  // jsddm funcs from http://javascript-array.com/scripts/jquery_simple_drop_down_menu/
  function jsddm_open($this){
    jsddm_canceltimer();
    jsddm_close();
    ddmenuitem = $this.find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');
  }

  function jsddm_close() {
    if(ddmenuitem){
      ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
      ddmenuitem = null;
    }
  }

  function jsddm_timer() { 
    closetimer = window.setTimeout(jsddm_close, timeout);
  }

  function jsddm_canceltimer() { 
    if(closetimer)
    {  window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
       closetimer = null;
    }
  }

  function jsddm_toggle($this) {
    if (ddmenuitem && $this.has(ddmenuitem[0]).length){
      jsddm_close();
    }
    else {
      jsddm_open($this);
    }
  }

  $.fn.make_dropdown = function(options){

    return this.each(function(){

      if (options && options['timeout']){
        timeout = options['timeout'];
      }

      $(this).click(function(event){
        jsddm_toggle($(this));
        event.stopPropagation();
      });
      if (!isTouch){
        $(this).mouseover(function(){ jsddm_open($(this)) }).mouseout(jsddm_timer);
      }

    });
  }

  $(document).click(jsddm_close);
  $('#showInput').click(jsddm_open);

})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){   $('#menubar > li').make_dropdown(); });
```